# Where does non-model logic go in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 7.x project. One of my controller methods is starting to get beefy with logic that does not belong in a model. It is code that can be re-used by other controllers. I would like to abstract it and make it available to the controller as a helper function. In the Laravel world, where would such logic go? Is it a `Provider`? Where in the documentation should I be looking to move this controller logic out so any other controller or possibly even models in the future can invoke said function?

Comment: I would suggest either use service classes or php traits.

Comment: You can just define `helpers` or `components` and based upon the usage you can either define the member functions with `static` keyword or just normal functions. The choice is all yours.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Services` for tings like this. My services contains business logic, and one service always handle single model. As example my simple service:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Company;


class CompanyService
{
    public function create(array $data) {

        // some another business logic here

        return Company::create($data)
    }

}
```

Then i can use this service very easy with dependency injection inside Controllers:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Company\Company;
use App\Services\CompanyService;

final class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    /** @var CompanyService */
    private $companyService;

    public function __construct(CompanyService $companyService)
    {
        $this->companyService = $companyService;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public Function store($request) {
        $company = $this->companyService->create( $request->validated() );
    
        return $company->toArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no "right way" todo that, I guess. But, for standardization, you are looking for "Repositories".

Can you create one "Base Repository" for all your default CRUD and some specializations when it is necessary.

My environment:

- Http
- - Controllers
- Models
- Repositories

Read more:

> https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce

> https://asperbrothers.com/blog/implement-repository-pattern-in-laravel/